# Error "_init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" when trying to build a CNN model using PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have recently started to learn coding with PyTorch. While I was trying to build a CNN model for the FashionMNIST dataset, I encountered the following problem :

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 model = CNN (K)

TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I have read the answers to similar questions but still, I am not able to solve my problem. I would be deeply grateful if anyone could help me in this regard.

Here is the code:

```
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST (root = '.', train = True, transform = transforms.ToTensor (), download= True)
test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST (root = '.', train= False, transform = transforms.ToTensor (), download = True)

K = len (set (train_dataset.targets.numpy ()))
class CNN (nn.Module):
  def __int__ (self, K):

    super (CNN, self).__int__ ()

    self.conv_layers = nn.Sequential (
    nn.Conv2d (in_channels= 1, out_channels= 32, kernel_size= 3, stride = 2),
    nn.ReLU (),
    nn.Conv2d (in_channels= 32, out_channels= 64, kernel_size= 3, stride = 2),
    nn.ReLU (),
    nn.Conv2d (in_channels= 64, out_channels= 128, kernel_size= 3, stride= 2),
    nn.ReLU ()
    )

    self.dense_layers = nn.Sequential (nn.Dropout (0.2),
                                   nn.Linear (128 * 2 * 2, 512),
                                   nn.ReLU (),
                                   nn.Dropout (0.2),
                                   nn.Linear (512, K)
                                   )
   def forward (self, x):
   out = self.conv_layers (x)
   out = out.view (out.size (0), -1)
   out = self.dense_layers (out)
   return out
```

Comment: Plz mark any one as correct if that helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your initializer method head: it should be `def __init__`, not `def __int__`.

Comment: I am very thankful for your precise obsevation, Ivan.  My problem was solved after I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 0):

You could try deleting "self" in your `def forward(self, x):` line, since it's already inside your object... I'm not really sure about that, but it seems that one of the "self" arguments are not required since you are already inside your obj class.

Comment: I am grateful for your response. The problem was actually a typo in my code.